# How to start Translate Animation in random order in Android?

Tags: android, animation, random

I have 3 Translate Animation to be played when the app starts -

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -1500, 1500);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
myimage.startAnimation(animation);
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

Animation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -1000, 1000);
animation2.setDuration(1000);
animation2.setFillAfter(false);
myimage2.startAnimation(animation2);
animation2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

Animation animation3 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -500, 500);
animation3.setDuration(1000);
animation3.setFillAfter(false);
myimage3.startAnimation(animation3);
animation3.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

I want to start the above 3 in random order, not necessarily the first one first.

One full day gone and I'm still unable to find a solution.
Any pointers on how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate `random` number in java and do switch

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = 3;

switch(random.nextInt(num)) {
     case 0: 
         animateFirst();
          break;
     case 1: 
          animateSecond();
          break;
     case 2: 
         animateThird();
          break;

}
```

Comment: but it says random order. i think its like 3,2,1 or 2,1,3. just my thinking

Comment: how would you random 3 possible numbers. what is the probability of 1 out of 3, 2 out 3 or 3 out 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way I got, modifying your code, @Murtaza Hussain

```
switch(random.nextInt(num)) {
         case 0: 
             animateFirst();
             animateSecond();
             animateThird();
              break;
         case 1: 
              animateSecond();
              animateFirst();
              animateThird();
              break;
         case 2: 
             animateFirst();
             animateThird();
             animateSecond();
              break;

    }
```